# OutOfMemoryException when showing a listview with videos thumbnail

Tags: android, video, imageview, android-bitmap

i need to pick multiple videos from gallery, and I've implemented a custom gallery starting from https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick .
When i'm loading thumbnails in the adapter, it gives me OutOfMemoryException after i starti the gallery Activity twice sequentially.

The code on adapter:

```
 VideoThumbnailImageLoader thumb=
                new VideoThumbnailImageLoader(
                        thumbPath,
                        MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

        holder.imgQueue.setImage(thumb,
                R.drawable.no_media);
```

and the `VideoThumbnailImageLoader` code:

```
public class VideoThumbnailImageLoader implements SmartImage {
private String videoPath;
private int thumbnailKind;

public VideoThumbnailImageLoader(String videoPath, int thumbnailKind) {
    this.videoPath=videoPath;
    this.thumbnailKind=thumbnailKind;
}

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(Context ctxt) {
    return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
}
```

}

I'm using http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/ to load video thumbnail.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Check : http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: It can load only URL Images, i need video thumbnail of SDCard or internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

Set android:largeHeap="true" in your activity proAndroidManifest.xml

Comment: A lot of devs says that it's not safe to activare LargeHeap on Manifest.

Comment: yes right you can use Picasso library for load image

Comment: Picasso doesn't load from Bitmap object, only from url or path